# Kotlin smartcasting approximates due to nulls in using the when

Tags: casting, match, instance, kotlin

I would like to share some knowledge that I have found regarding Kotlin [when expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression): the Kotlin documentation, even though written as simple and forthcoming as I can imagine it written, does ask for a very holistic understanding.

Two things that was not immediately clear were:

1. How would the when statement match multiple instances that are nullable?
2. How do you match based on a function call?

Without getting verbose, I will simply give you the code and its results.  The findings are commented in the code. There were definitely a few (in hindsight) obvious things that I missed on first take for the when statement - but there are a few eye openers as well.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: the only thing to know about `when` is that semantically it is equivalent to an `if-else` cascade. And it is stated the docs

Comment: Even when answering your own question, the question has to be stated that would be being asked, and be judged stand-alone from the answer.  So if you don't make it clear what question the answer is for (by having a good question), this could be closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * If smaller returns value, then the when statement sees it as a matching case
 */
fun smaller(value: Int, lt: Int) = if (value < lt) value else lt

fun whenTest(value: Int = 5) = when(value) {
    smaller(value, 1) -> "Smaller than 1"
    in 1..4 -> "Smaller than Five"
    5 -> "Five"
    else -> "Larger than 5"
}

/*
    IMPORTANT NOTES ABOUT INSTANCE TESTS:
    1. Evaluation is sequential from top to bottom
    2. Smartcasting will, for a box or unboxed type enter the first boxed or unboxed type, whichever is first
        (see case x...).  This is for if an Int? contains an int it enters Int ->, and when it contains a null
        then it enters null ->
    3. Smartcasting on a null value will enter the first null or nullable type case!!!  If you switch case c: and
        x: around then case x: may execute while case c: will never ever execute


 */
fun patternTest(value: Any?) = when (value) {
    10 -> "e: the value is ten"
    is String -> "a: a string of $value"
    is Int -> "b: an int of $value"
    null -> "c: the value is null"
    is Int? -> "x: never ever executed: an int of $value"
    else -> "d: ${value.javaClass.name} class with value of $value"
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Performing whenTest")

    println("whenTest(-1) = ${whenTest(-1)}")
    println("whenTest(2) = ${whenTest(2)}")
    println("whenTest(5) = ${whenTest(5)}")
    println("whenTest(7) = ${whenTest(7)}")

    val nullableInt : Int? = 200
    val nonNullableInt : Int = 200
    val nulledInt: Int? = null
    println("patternTest(-1) = ${patternTest(-1)}")
    println("patternTest($nullableInt) = ${patternTest(nullableInt)}")
    println("patternTest($nonNullableInt) = ${patternTest(nonNullableInt)}")
    println("patternTest($nulledInt) = ${patternTest(nulledInt)}")
    println("patternTest(null) = ${patternTest(null)}")
    println("patternTest(123.45f) = ${patternTest(123.45f)}")
    println("patternTest(10) = ${patternTest(10)}")
}
```

And here is the output:

```
Performing whenTest
whenTest(-1) = Smaller than 1
whenTest(2) = Smaller than Five
whenTest(5) = Five
whenTest(7) = Larger than 5
patternTest(-1) = b: an int of -1
patternTest(200) = b: an int of 200
patternTest(200) = b: an int of 200
patternTest(null) = c: the value is null
patternTest(null) = c: the value is null
patternTest(123.45f) = d: java.lang.Float class with value of 123.45
patternTest(10) = e: the value is ten
```

Comment: I think there should be an inspection that would give a warning on more than one `is T? ->` block in `when`. It should say that all `null`s will be matched earlier and there should be non-nullable type instead. You might file an issue at youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT.